# $http.get request is only successful on first page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Here's the scenario: a user visits `http://localhost:3000/all`, and a list of all users are displayed on the page.  Great, that's what I want.  But, when I refresh the page, I lose everything (no HTML is rendered).  I'm just left with a raw JSON output that is being returned by the server.

The relevant sections of my Angular file:

```
var app = angular.module('social', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ui.router'])

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
    })
   .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
    })
   .when('/signup', {
    templateUrl: 'signup.html',
    controller: 'SignupController'
    })
   .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html'
    })
   .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    controller: 'UserProfileController',
   })
   .when('/all', {
    templateUrl: 'members.html',
    controller: 'MembersController',
    resolve: {
        allMembers: function($http) {
            return $http.get('/all').then(function(res) {
                return res.data
            })
        }
    }
   })
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
})

app.controller('MembersController', function($http, $scope, $cookies) {
    function getAllUsers() {
        $http.get('/all').then(function(res) {
            $scope.members = res.data
        })
    }
    getAllUsers()
})
```

You'll notice I attempted to use `resolve` in `app.config`, but that didn't help (I'm probably using it incorrectly).  When using `resolve`, my controller becomes:

```
app.controller('MembersController', function(allMembers, $scope) {
    $scope.members = allMembers
})
```

I get the same result: data loads fine on initial page load, but upon refresh, I'm left with raw JSON on the page.

The relevant part in the server (using Mongoose):

```
app.get('/all', function(req, res, next) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        return res.json(users)
    })
})
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I followed an online tutorial before trying this on my own, and it worked fine in the tutorial (obviously).

Comment: This is wrong and is a bad practice: `if (err) console.log(err)`, because users will not contain anything. You should return HTTP 400 or 500 depending on what happened, and a sanitized error.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "users will not contain anything".  Changing it to `if (err) throw err` didn't seem to make a difference, and I'm not sure how this relates to the problem I'm facing.

Comment: If you throw the error you will leak everything associated with the request, including the client connection, this is even worse and the easiest way to drive your service over capacity. You need to send an error response, not throw. Unless you have an error handling middleware that catches the exception thrown from the route and returns the error response.
However, such error handlers do not work for asynchronous code, only synchronous code.

Just do `return next(error)`

Comment: So, this?

`app.get('/all', function(req, res, next) {
 User.find(function(err, users) {
  if (err) return next(err)
  return res.json(users)
 })
})`

Comment: Yes. In addition try to add an express error handling middleware and you should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

That’s expected.

It seems that only your `/` route is serving the angular application.

The `/all` route is your API, so when you’re requesting it (after refreshing the page), your browser will render what the server sends – which is `res.json(users)`.

What you probably want to do is namespace your API.

You could create an API router:

```
const app = express();
const api = express.Router();
api.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    // ...
    res.json(users);
});

// ...

app.use('/api', api);
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('path/to/your/index.html');
});
```

This will make sure that all routes, except for your API routes, will serve your angular application.